# How to call an overloaded oracle procedure via c#

Tags: c#, oracle, overloading, odp.net

I have two procedures in a package (TEST_PAK) that are overloaded on Oracle 9i.  One takes a string and one takes an array as parameters.  The problem i run into is when i try to call with null as a parameter.  I am using C# and ODP.NET to call the procedures.

Here's the head of the two procs:

```
PROCEDURE get_requests_with_files
(
    o_results OUT sys_refcursor, 
    in_communicator IN VARCHAR2, 
    in_state        IN VARCHAR2  -- State of requests wanted (use NULL for ALL records)
)
```

and

```
PROCEDURE get_requests_with_files
(
     o_results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,    
     in_communicator IN VARCHAR2,    
     in_states       IN flagTableType 
)
```

The flagTypeTable is how i pass in a PLSQLAssociativeArray to my procedure and not really a part of the problem (i think).

Here's the C# code i use to call the proc.

```
private static DataSet GetRequests(String consumer, List<string> states)
{
    try
    {
        const string query = "TEST_PAK.get_requests_with_files";

        var retVal = new DataSet();
        var oComm = new OracleCommand(query, _oConn);
        var oDa = new OracleDataAdapter(oComm);
        oComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oComm.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout;

        //Parameters

        oComm.Parameters.Add("o_results", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        oComm.Parameters["o_results"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        oComm.Parameters.Add("in_communicator", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        oComm.Parameters["in_communicator"].Value = consumer;

        if (states.Count != 0)
        {
            oComm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("in_states", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
            {
                CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
                Value = states.ToArray()
            });
        }
        else
        {
            oComm.Parameters.Add("in_state", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            oComm.Parameters["in_state"].Value = null;
        }

        _oConn.Open();

        oDa.Fill(retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (_oConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) _oConn.Close();
    }
}
```

I have tried placing colons in front of the parameters thinking the named parameters would do the trick with no luck.

I know i can call the code in SQLDeveloper like this:

```
variable o_results refcursor;
execute Apps.Base_communicator.get_requests_with_files(:o_results, in_communicator => 'MYCOMM', in_state => null);
print o_results;
```

So i know the overloads work, just not how to call them in c#

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Years since C#, but should `oComm.Parameters["in_state"].Value = null;` be `oComm.Parameters["in_state"].Value = DBNull.value;`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx

Comment: The Error I am getting is PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'get_requests_with_files' match this call.  I tried the DBNull idea just now and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution was to add `BindByName` to the `OracleCommand` object.  Doing this (and removing the colons) allowed it to bind to the variables by name.  This let the overloads work as long as the names were different.